# Goals and Callbacks in CPLEX+Java: Nonlinear Pre-processing

Tags: java, callback, cplex

I have a problem in which I want to insert new solutions in CPLEX. Originally, I did this using a Heuristic Callback. The problem here is that the following is ignored:

```
model.setParam(IloCplex.Param.Preprocessing.Linear,1);
```

(I know that this happens because of the Control Callback). The problem is: The non-linear preprocessing would help me a lot to bring down the lower bound on the cost (otherwise, I cannot prove optimality).

I did some research online, and found that I can also add a solution using Goals, in particular Solution Goals.

I now use a Solution goal, which in brevity looks as follows:

```
private class InsertSolution2 extends IloCplex.Goal {
    @Override
    public IloCplex.Goal execute(IloCplex iloCplex) throws IloException {
        if (nextSolution != null) {
            System.out.println("In Solution Goal: Next Solution Exists");
            //inject solution
            //set values for vars and vals
            nextSolution = null;
            return cplex.solutionGoal(vars, vals);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I then add this to `cplex.solve(new InsertSolution2())`

This gives me a few problems (but I am a complete beginner with goals ...)

- Is the above correct?
- How is it implemented in the backend? It still ignores the preprocessing ... Is there an alternative which allows non-linear preprocessing?
- Is this in conflict with start solutions? My start solutions are now being ignored ...

Thank you!
Layla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that using goals is going to help you. Goals are implemented using callbacks, so there is nothing you can achieve with goals that you cannot achieve with callbacks.

But instead of using the heuristic callback to inject a feasible solution you could try to use the new generic callback framework. This framework was designed to overcome exactly the problem you describe. In this framework you can for example active the `GLOBAL_PROGRESS` context and post heuristic solutions from there. See the `AdMIPex9.java` example that ships with CPLEX for an example of how to inject feasible solutions from the generic callback during tree search.

Comment: that already helps alot. I have two minor follow-up questions: 
a) is there an equivalent to `hasIncumbent()` 
b) is there a pendant to `getIncumbentValues()`(I saw that I can query them individually, but I was hoping to retrieve them as an array)

Comment: and actually one more: since updating CPLEX, it tells me that "MIPEmphasis" is deprecated. Googling didn't help to see with what I should replace it to make sure that CPLEX focuses on proving optimality (I can generate very good solutions heuristically)

Comment: and CPLEX now seems to operate in a multi-threading mode, can I surpress this?

Comment: The equivalent thing for `hasIncumbent()` is `Context.getIntInfo(Context.Info.Feasible) != 0`. To query multiple incumbent values at the same time use `Context.getIncumbent(IloNumVar[])`.
About the parameter: only its name is deprecated. The new name is `IloCplex.Param.Emphasis.MIP`, see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/MIPEmphasis.html.
So supress multi-threading set `IloCplex.Param.Threads` to 1.